# Axios async await Cloud Function returning before axios completes post request

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

I have a react app, with a message page. The message page allows the user to submit a message. The submission process sends the message info to a Cloud Function deployed on Firebase Functions (Google Cloud). The function responds with an object like this:

```
{
    success: true,
    message: 'Your message has been sent.'
}
```

This is the cloud function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const fs = admin.firestore()

const axios = require('axios')

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (input) => {
    try {
        let outcome = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
            params: {
                secret: --redacted--,
                response: input.recaptchaToken
            }
        })
        outcome.data.success && fs.collection("messages").add({
            timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            name: input.name,
            email: input.email,
            message: input.message
        })
        return outcome.data.success ? {
            success: true,
            message: 'Your message has been sent.'
        } : {
            success: false,
            message: `Your message failed. You're a robot.`
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Cloud Function error:', error)
        return {
            success: false,
            message: 'Your message failed. Try again later.'
        }
    }
})
```

However, it isn't working as intended. The message **successfully** writes to Firestore, however the object I receive back is `success: false, message: 'Your message failed. Try again later.''`

The error I get from logging on Cloud Function is this:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
at exports.testSendMessage.functions.https.onCall
```

... which implies that the function isn't waiting for axios to resolve with a response (even though it does later), and is instead continuing on with the function, resulting in the error.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReferenceError: data is not defined` is telling you that `outcome.data` is undefined.  You should do more logging to determine why `outcome` is something other than what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Doug. So I added a console.log(outcome) after the await axios section. On the console logs on Firebase, it shows up as this unexpected object `{ status: 200,`
I think, logically, I'm doing something wrong in regards to async await, and promises, and I have fundamentally misunderstood something, because the messages are still added to firestore as I want them to, but the function just isn't waiting before returning something to my front end.

Comment: I think you just have to deal with `outcome` exactly as you see it.  Don't access properties on the object that don't exist.  The 200 status suggests that the requests succeeded.  But we don't know what you're expecting as the full response, so there's not much else to suggest.

Comment: Yep, figured it out. I’m a dumbass. I was referencing “data” somewhere else (didn’t paste that part of the function because of privacy) and never changed it to “input.”